# Why htmltextbox property .selectable=false doesnt work on actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have this code:

```
function displayHTML(htmlText:String):void
  {
   var mcArray:Array = new Array();

   for (var i:int=0; i<20; i++) {
      var caja1:HTMLTextBlock = new HTMLTextBlock();
      dragMe.addChild(caja1);
      mcArray[i] = caja1;
   }

   for (var i:int=0; i<20; i++) {   
   mcArray[i].blockWidth = 720;
   mcArray[i].textStyleSheet = textStyleSheet;
   mcArray[i].setHTML(htmlText);
   mcArray[i].selectable = false; 
   mcArray[i].x = 0;
   mcArray[i].y = i*(mcArray[i].height+40);
   }
  }
```

But the property selectable (mcArray[i].selectable = false; ) seems to be not working as i want, the flash console give this error: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Without that line of code, all works fine, but i dont want the user to select text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is regarding the HTMLTextBlock class from this tutorial I wrote:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design/master-html-formatted-text-in-flash/

The text field you are trying to target is actually a child of the HTMLTextBlock class. There are a few ways you can accomplish what you are trying to do. The best way would probably be to add a new method to the HTMLTextBlock class that sets the property.

Add this method after the setHTML() method:

```
public function setSelectable(value:Boolean):void
{
    htmlTextField.selectable = value;
}
```

Then, in your displayHTML function, do:

```
mcArray[i].setSelectable(false);
```

Comment: i get this error now: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 87 1119: Access of possibly undefined property selectable through a reference with static type HTMLTextBlock.

Comment: Be sure you are setting the selectable property on the TextField inside the HTMLTextBlock class, not the HTMLTextBlock itself

Answer (score 1):

HTMLTextBlock is not a core class? Does it extend TextField, or does it wrap TextField, you will need to get a handle on the text field property if it exists and set the selectable flag there.